# Dynamically changing pan of audio stream in Swift, using an HLS (m3u8) source

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, core-audio, http-live-streaming

For the last couple of days I have been trying to find a way of dynamically  changing (during playback) the 'pan' value of a stereo audio stream in a video being streamed over HLS. The end result that I want is to be able to mute the right channel or left channel during video playback. I thought it would be simple.

I have tried a couple of options, neither of which have brought me any joy and would very much appreciate any pointers which might solve my problems. I'll outline what I have tried - hopefully someone will be able to help.

**Attempt the First**
I have tried using Apple's `MTAudioProcessingTap`. I did read in a variety of comments that it isn't possible to use this over HLS - but thought it worth giving it a go. Here is a sample of my code:

```
if let playerItem = player?.currentItem, let audioTrack = getAudioTrack(playerItem: playerItem) {
    let inputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)
    let callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(version: kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0,
                                                  clientInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()),
                                                  init: tapInit,
                                                  finalize: tapFinalize,
                                                  prepare: tapPrepare,
                                                  unprepare: tapUnprepare,
                                                  process: tapProcess)

     let err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks!, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap)
     assert(tap != nil)
     inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tap!.takeunRetainedValue()

     let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
     audioMix.inputParameters = [inputParams]
     playerItem.audioMix = audioMix
}
```

I noticed that the tapInit callback does get called, however none of the other callbacks are called until tapFinalize. When loading the file in locally, all the callbacks get hit as I would expect, including the process callback. As a result of this, I have not attempted to actually alter the pan value.

**Attempt the Second**
I have tried to make use of the CoreAudio API. Despite setting everything up as I would expect I need to, I never see any impact on the audio output when loading the content over HLS or locally. Here is my setup:

```
var processingGraph: AUGraph? = nil
var status = OSStatus(noErr)
var mixerUnit: AudioUnit? = nil
var outputUnit: AudioUnit? = nil

status = NewAUGraph(&processingGraph)

var mixerNode = AUNode()
var mixerUnitDescription = AudioComponentDescription(
    componentType:         OSType(kAudioUnitType_Mixer),
    componentSubType:      OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer),
    componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
    componentFlags:        0,
    componentFlagsMask:    0)

var outputNode = AUNode()
var outputUnitDescription = AudioComponentDescription(
    componentType:         OSType(kAudioUnitType_Output),
    componentSubType:      OSType(kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO),
    componentManufacturer: OSType(kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple),
    componentFlags:        0,
    componentFlagsMask:    0)

status = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph!, &outputUnitDescription, &outputNode)
status = AUGraphAddNode(processingGraph!, &mixerUnitDescription, &mixerNode)

let outputElement = AudioUnitElement(0)
let mixerElement = AudioUnitElement(0)
status = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph!, mixerNode, mixerElement, outputNode, outputElement)

status = AUGraphNodeInfo(processingGraph!, mixerNode, nil, &mixerUnit)
status = AUGraphNodeInfo(processingGraph!, outputNode, nil, &outputUnit)

status = AUGraphOpen(processingGraph!)

var outIsInited: DarwinBoolean = false
status = AUGraphIsInitialized(processingGraph!, &outIsInited)
if outIsInited == false {
    print("Need to init graph")
    status = AUGraphInitialize(processingGraph!)
}

var isRunning: DarwinBoolean = false
status = AUGraphIsRunning(processingGraph!, &isRunning)
if isRunning == false {
    print("Need to start graph")
    status = AUGraphStart(processingGraph!)
}
```

I am then setting the pan value thus:

```
status = AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerUnit!, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, panValue, 0)
```

I don't know whether I have missed a step with the above setup as the fact that no change takes place even on the local file baffles me a little.

**Attempt the Third**
This really hasn't gone very far, but I came across the [Superpowered SDK](http://superpowered.com/) which I noticed contained a class called [SuperpoweredStereoMixer](http://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_stereo_mixer.html), which suggests it should be possible to control pan:

> Separate input channel levels (good for gain and pan), separate output channel levels (master gain and pan)

There is so little documentation, though, that I am struggling to get started and remain concerned that this library may not solve adjusting the pan value over HLS.